# Materialize CSS empty fields validation on submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, materialize

First of all, thanks for your time reviewing my question and trying to help me. I have been working on an App where I use Materialize CSS form to gather user's inputs. However, I have been having a hard time to validate empty fields when the user press the submit button.

Below is my code, so you can have a better idea of what I have. I need to come up with some javascript to validate empty fields when the user press the submit button on the form. I am having a hard time to create this, since I have nested object to fetch to my API. I tried creating a for in loop to iterate on the object but had no success on it.

Any insights on this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks Again

```js
let btnSave = document.getElementById("btnSaveGift");
      btnSave.addEventListener("click", APP.addGift);


addGift() {
    //user clicked the save gift button in the modal
    let gift = {
      name: document.getElementById("name").value,
      price: document.getElementById("price").value,
      store: {
        name: document.getElementById("storeName").value,
        productURL: document.getElementById("storeProductURL").value
      }
    }

    //validating the inputs - still working on it.
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal modal-fixed-footer center" id="modalAddGift">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>New Gift idea</h4>
        <p>Why not add another idea?</p>
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 black-text">
              <input id="name" type="text" class="validate black-text" class="validate" required="" 
              aria-required="true"/>
              <label for="name" class="black-text">Idea</label>
              <span class="helper-text" data-error="please try again"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 black-text">
              <input id="price" type="number" inputmode="numeric" class="validate black-text" class="validate" required=""
              aria-required="true"/>
              <label for="price" class="black-text">Price</label>
              <span class="helper-text" data-error="invalid price"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 black-text">
              <input id="storeName" type="text" class="validate black-text" class="validate" required=""
              aria-required="true"/>
              <label for="storeName" class="black-text">Store Name</label>
              <span class="helper-text" data-error="please try again"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 black-text">
              <input id="storeProductURL" type="url" class="validate black-text" class="validate" required=""
              aria-required="true"/>
              <label for="storeProductURL" class="black-text">Website</label>
              <span class="helper-text" data-error="invalid URL"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer light-blue">
        <a
          href="#!"
          id="btnSaveGift"
          class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat white-text"
          >Save Gift Idea</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validating your inputs values shouldn't be that difficult, since the `addGift()` function gets called when the submit button is clicked and the `gift` objct is generated within it. then your validation can take effect using a simple if statement:

```
// validating
if(!gift.name || !gift.price 
    || !gift.store.name || !gift.store.productURL ){ // This checks for any false value

    // What action you want to take goes here
} else{
   // What to do when all fields are true goes here!
}
```